# Inline `ng-template` not found by `ng-include`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-templates, angularjs-ng-template

I have a view being loaded with an embedded `text/ng-template` which is not being found by a `ng-include` later in the file. The script block sits at the very top of the view file:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="stringCondition">
    <!-- template guts -->
</script>
```

Which I am loading later in the file with:

```
<ng-include src="'stringCondition'"></ng-include>
```

But is producing a 404 error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost/~me/stringCondition 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried several variants on naming (like having .html on the end) and using `ng-include` as an attribute instead of the high level element. All with no luck.

What could be causing an embedded `ng-template` to not be registering with an `ng-include` in the same view file?

UPDATE:

As comments and answers have pointed out, the basic design of my code is correct. But something is causing `ng-template` to (apparently) fail to make the template available to the system.

I updated my code to pull from a HTML file (instead of an imbedded template) and it works fine.

Is there a common situation that I could be running into that breaks `ng-template`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nozbaveq/ working for me. So the issue is not this part of code :)

Comment: @ehlers - yup, something weird is going on, see update on getting it working with regular files. Something is breaking `ng-template` but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 15):

```html
<div ng-app>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="stringCondition">
     Yes, yes it did.
  </script>
  Did it work? <ng-include src="'stringCondition'"></ng-include>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I had the same problem and came upon this post. I can now see what is causing this issue so hopefully this is helps anyone else with this issue.

The reason rgthree's code works is that the script tag for text/ng-template has to live within the scope of ng-app. So it is fine to have the template in a seperate .js file but just make sure when it is rendered on the HTML page it is within ng-app, otherwise angular won't be aware of it and will attempt to load it from the server.

Comment: Superb explanation as your answer help me to resolve my issue which was happening exactly what you stated in your answer.+1

Comment: Thanks, saved three days of research and try and error

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me. Perhaps you have something else going on outside of your example code.

```html
<div ng-app>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="stringCondition">
     Yes, yes it did.
  </script>
  Did it work? <ng-include src="'stringCondition'"></ng-include>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Something definitely is screwing with my ability to use `ng-template`. I pulled out the code into a file and it is working fine, but I'd rather keep it to the `script` to keep down the file count. This is weird, I'm not sure what is killing the `ng-template` capabilities.